# C++ API realtime currency conversion

Tags: c++, api

I'm working on a school project for a currency converter with 5 currencies, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to get value from a website [xe](https://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/) like the Philippine peso to USD. I know I can just get the value from the website and set it in an array or int, but I want it to be a Realtime conversion of the currency itself. Is there a way to do that, and if so, how?

I only have 2 day to finish this project of mine because my professor gave us only a little bit of time

this is the code that I've got for now

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int picked[5] = {0,0,0,0,0};

int main()
{
   string currentvalue[5][5] = {{"1","2","3","4","5"},{"6","7","8","9","10"},{"11","12","13","14","15"},{"16","17","18","19","20"},{"21","22","23","24","25"}};
   string currency[5] = {"Philippine Peso","euro","pounds","yen","usd"};
   int yourcurrency;
   int convert;
int timesToRun = 5;
int number = 1;
   
   
   cout << "Choose your currency \n" << endl;
   
       for (int counter = 0 ; counter < timesToRun; counter++)
   {
       cout << number;
       cout << "." + currency[counter] << endl;
       number++;
   
       
   }
       cout << "\nOption: ";
       cin >> yourcurrency;
       system("CLS");
       yourcurrency = yourcurrency - 1;
       
       picked[yourcurrency] = 1;
       cout << "Select your currency you want to convert into \n" << endl;
    number = 1;
       
   for (int counter = 0; counter < timesToRun; counter++)
   {
       if (picked[counter] != 1){
       cout << number;
       cout << "." + currency[counter] << endl;
       number++;
       }
   }
   
   
       cout << "\nOption: ";
       cin >> convert;
       if (convert > yourcurrency ){
           convert;
       }
       system("CLS");

   cout << currency[yourcurrency]+ " - " + currency[convert];
                   cout << " [" + currentvalue[yourcurrency][convert] + "] " << endl;
                   cout << "Amount: ";
                       
                       int cash;
                       cin >> cash;
                       int value = stoi(currentvalue[yourcurrency][convert]);
                       int total = cash * value;
                       cout << currency[convert]<< ": " << total;
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I see `using namespace std;` and `system("CLS")`, I guess you are very early beginning C++ developer. This task may be difficult at this level.

Look at the menus on the site you reference. There is "Business & API" -> [Xe Currency Data API](https://www.xe.com/xecurrencydata/).

1. Register and start your free trial. You will get trial authentication tokens.
2. Use any http client, for example [cpp-httplib](https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib), for retrieving actual data using the API.